# Time direction ambiguity in stationary observer's 4-velocity

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, time, conventions

Working in the mostly + convention, for a timelike geodesic in Minkowski spacetime we have the requirement that (c=1):
$$u^\alpha u_\alpha=-1$$
and that it of course obeys the geodesic equation.
If we consider a stationary observer located at the origin there are two vectors which satisfy such condition, namely
$$u^\alpha=(1,0,0,0)$$
and
$$u^\alpha=(-1,0,0,0)$$
Which of these describes is the future oriented one? And does it depend on the metric convention?
The idea I have is that in any convention the future oriented one should be the one with positive sign since for it we get that
$$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=1$$
Which means that it increases along the same direction as proper time.
But I'm not sure first of all because we define proper time with a sign according to coordinate time in each convention and this is therefore always true and also because choosing the mostly + metric might mean that we consider an inverted time axis and the negative 4-velocity then seems the more natural choice.